# Find non-Empty value in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict like this:

```
d = {'first':'', 'second':'', 'third':'value', 'fourth':''}
```

and I want to find first non-empty value (and it's name, in this example `'third'`). There may be more than one non-empty value, but I only want the first one I find.

How can I do this?

Comment: when you say "first": You know that a dictionary is unordered?

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, that list is for example, and I know that dictionaries are not ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `next` (dictionaries are unordered - this somewhat changed in Python 3.6 but that's only an implementation detail currently) to get one "not-empty" key-value pair:

```
>>> next((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v)
('third', 'value')
```

Comment: Even in Python 3.6 this is only an implementation detail and may change anytime: "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and **should not be relied upon**" https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict

Comment: @DeepSpace You're right. I always "ignore" that it's just an implementation details. It's too handy to think of them as ordered now :)

Comment: Elegant. I changed the return value to get a dict as well: `d = next({k: v} for k, v in f.items() if v)`

Answer (score 7):

Use an `OrderedDict` which preserves the order of elements. Then loop over them and find the first that isn't empty:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
# fill d
for key, value in d.items():
    if value:
        print(key, " is not empty!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
def none_empty_finder(dict):
    for e in dict:
        if dict[e] != '':
            return [e,dict[e]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'first':'', 'second':'', 'third':'value', 'fourth':''}
for k, v in d.items():
    if v!='':
        return k, v
```

**Edit 1**

`from the comment` if the value is `None` or `''` we better use `if v:` instead of `if v!=''`. `if v!=''` only check the `''` and skip others

Comment: You can type `if v:` in case that'll skip when v is `{}` or `None` or `''`

Answer (score 1):

You can find empty elements and make a list of them:

```
 non_empty_list = [(k,v) for k,v in a.items() if v]
```

Answer (score 0):

By using list comprehension, you can list all the non-empty values and then fetch the 0th value:

```
[val for key, val in d.items() if val][0]
```

Comment: Provided there actually is one element with a value in there .... otherwise it will error on index not found.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.7 dictionary has got insertion-order preservation:
https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html

Thefore something like this would work fine since then:

```
lst = [v for k, v in d.items() if v]

val = lst[0] if lst else None
```